# Test simple Ajax- Success Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jasmine

I'm trying to test this simple Ajax-Request with Jasmine:

```
var Card = {
    single : function(params){
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {"X-TOKEN": TOKEN},
            url: SERVER,
            success: function(data,status,xhr){
                params.params['card'] = data['card'];
                params.callback(params.params); 
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    ErrorHandler.connection(xhr,status,error);
            }
        });
    },
```

My test code:

```
       it("should call Callback with appropiate Callbacks", function(){
            var Meth = {test_method: function(params){}};
            spyOn(Meth,"test_method");
            spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake(function(e) {
                 e.success('one','two','three');
            });
            Card.single({id: 2, params: {callback: Meth.test_method}});
            expect(Meth.test_method).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

I simply cannot understand why my test doesn't work! Instead i get a error that something is undefined:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

In this line of the Jasmine Libary jasmine.js 2108:

```
this.result.failedExpectations.push(this.expectationResultFactory(data));
```

What do I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Well `params.callback(params.params);` is wrong

Comment: Oh thanks! Do you know a solution how i could pass params to this `success`-Block? Thanks!

Comment: No the callback will not be called since you are not referencing correct...

Comment: @epascarello could you please write a answer to this question? And explain how i should test the Ajax-Success? Thanks

Comment: I do not know the answer, all I know is the callback is wrong since it is not part of params and using params inside of params is a bad pattern since it is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing

```
params.params['card'] = data['card'];
params.callback(params.params);
```

to

```
params.params['card'] = data['card'];
params.params.callback(params.params);
```

Also to unit test Ajax, it is often easier to use sinon (http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server) inside jasmine beforeEach and afterEach like so.

```
beforeEach(function() {
    this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  });

afterEach(function() {
  this.server.restore();
 });
```

in your test you can then mock out the call like so

this.server.requests[0].respond(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                                 '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]');

Finally you can check your spy to see if it was called

Answer (score 0):

`spy.and.callFake()` will delegate calls to the function and not cll the original function at all. http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Spies:_`and.callFake`

Failing example without the ajax call

```
describe('test', function () {
    it("should call Callback with appropiate Callbacks", function(){
        var called = false;
        var Meth = {test_method: function(params){
            called = true;
        }};
        spyOn(Meth,"test_method").and.callFake(function(){
        });
        Meth.test_method();
        expect(Meth.test_method).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(called).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Passing example without the ajax call

```
describe('test', function () {
    it("should call Callback with appropiate Callbacks", function(){
        var called = false;
        var Meth = {test_method: function(params){
        }};
        spyOn(Meth,"test_method").and.callFake(function(){
            called = true;
        });
        Meth.test_method();
        expect(Meth.test_method).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(called).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But i would like to test the Ajax-Success Callback!